# get column name that contains a specific value in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I want to get column name from the whole database (assume the database contains more than 100 rows with more than 50 column) based on specific value that contain in a specific column in pandas.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6], 'C':[7,8,9]})
pos = 2
response = raw_input("input")
placeholder = (df == response).idxmax(axis=1)[0]
print df
print (placeholder)
```

Tried a lot . . .

Example:
when the user will input 2; it will show answer: A
if the input is 4; feedback will be B
and if 7 then reply will be C

tried iloc but I've seen row have to be noticed there.

Please Help Dear Guys . . . . .
Thanks . . . :)

Comment: Give us an example

Comment: Hi There!

Okay, see:

import sqlite3
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

pos = 2
response = raw_input("input")
placeholder = (df == response).idxmax(axis=1)[0]
print df
print (placeholder)

I know idxmax is not the ideal way to do it as it is already taking me to the wrong decision/result and is not created to do such. but I could not found any better ways after a number of trying and now looking for your help, please . . .

Thank You . . . :)

Comment: Cast your response to int, like `response = int(raw_input("input"))` then do 
 `df.columns[(df == response).any()][0]`

Comment: @AndreyF I used `df.columns` not `df` so it will give the right output .

Comment: @Dark Oops. My bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
for i in df.columns:
    newDf = df.loc[lambda df: df[i] == response]
    if(not newDf.empty):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Hi There! Appreciating Your Help! But fall on another trouble now, if I do something like this:

    df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['APPLE','BALL','CAT'],
                   'B':['ACTION','BATMAN','CATCHUP'],
                   'C':['ADVERTISE','BEAST','CARTOON']})
    response = input("input")
    for i in df.columns:
    if(len(df.query(i + '==' + str(response))) > 0):
        print(i)

then output arise as error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    NameError: name 'APPLE' is not defined

What to do to get rid of this problem, Dear . . ?

Comment: I have edited the code. This is different approach than the previous one. I hope this helps.

Comment: It works fine, Bro! Bro, Can you help me with this one, please ! ? :)
[how-to-make-it-like-make-its-process-of-adding-automatically-based-on-keyword-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929823/how-to-make-it-like-make-its-process-of-adding-automatically-based-on-keyword-c)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should treat the input as integer. So instead of `raw_input`, use `input`:

```
response = input("input")
```

After that you can use `any`:

```
df[df==YOUR_VALUE].any()
```

This will return a boolean `Series` with columns names and whether they contain the value you are looking for.

In your example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6], 'C':[7,8,9]})
response = input("input")
placeholder = df[df==response].any()
```

for input 4 the output will be:

```
A    False
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: like this, dear . ?

import sqlite3
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

response = raw_input("input")
placeholder = df[df==response].any()
print df
print (placeholder)

resulting like this . . . :(

Output:
input2
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
A    False
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve... Edit your question and add an example