# How to make it like make it's process of adding automatically based on keyword count

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a form where if I input a medicine's name, it will show the solution of the medicine serially. But it is kind of limited bythe way I'm making it like more lines I'll code more spaces they will get to have the number of feedback. It would be great if you could help me to make something short but have the infinity process like loop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'FEVER':['NAPA_PLUS','JERIN','PARASITAMOL'],
               'GASTRIC':['SECLO40','SECLO20','ANTACID'],
               'WATERINESS':['ORSALINE','TESTY_SALINE','HOME_MADE_SALINE']})

def word_list(text):
return list(filter(None, re.split('\W+', text)))


session = raw_input("INPUT THE NAME OF THE MEDICINES ONE BY ONE BY KEEPING SPACE:")
feedback = session
print(word_list(feedback))


dff = pd.DataFrame({'itemlist':[feedback]})
dff['1'] = dff['itemlist'].astype(str).str.split().str[0]
dff['2'] = dff['itemlist'].astype(str).str.split().str[1]
dff['3'] = dff['itemlist'].astype(str).str.split().str[2]
dff['4'] = dff['itemlist'].astype(str).str.split().str[3]
dff['5'] = dff['itemlist'].astype(str).str.split().str[4]

for pts1 in dff['1']:
    pts1 = df.columns[df.isin([pts1]).any()]
for pts2 in dff['2']:
    pts2 = df.columns[df.isin([pts2]).any()]
for pts3 in dff['3']:
    pts3 = df.columns[df.isin([pts3]).any()]
for pts4 in dff['4']:
    pts4 = df.columns[df.isin([pts4]).any()]
for pts5 in dff['5']:
    pts5 = df.columns[df.isin([pts5]).any()]
```

Answer (score 1):

This wraps your repeated code into two loops:

```
...

dff = pd.DataFrame({'itemlist':[feedback]})
limit = 5

for i in xrange(limit):
    name = str(i+1)
    dff[name] = dff['itemlist'].astype(str).str.split().str[i]
    for pts in dff[name]:
        pts = df.columns[df.isin([pts]).any()]
```

Comment: Dear @ukemi ,
it's been long since I was not with my research. Thanks for the help! but a little more is need!

on my example if I wrote pts1 to print it showed the title the first word of what inputted. if i inputted two words in time of input; printing pts2 print out the second word's title from the database. but in your feedback how can i achieve this I mean i put three medicines name; how it will feedback me their fever type serially; it would be great if you could help me on this point too! :) Thank You!

Comment: @wh112 `ptsx` are the elements of `dff["x"]`. Access them explicitly through references to `dff`, don't rely on the last value of an iterable outside of its scope.

Comment: Dear @ukemi , maybe too much hard for me. :( a little example will be great . . . :/ :)